# Reflected wave in FFT?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, wave, decomposition

I'm trying to determine the reflective coefficient of sine wave. This one paper suggests a method using Fourier analysis. Here, it suggests

> Incident Wave = a cos(kx + Constant1),
>
> Reflected Wave = a cos(kx + Constant2),
>
> Wave = Incident Wave + Reflected Wave,
>
> Wave = A cos(x) + B sin(y),

Followed by some mathematical function to derive the coefficient. The input of this function is A and B. The paper states that they can be found using Fourier analysis without going into much detail.

I'm new to signal processing and I'm confused on how to find A and B, if I have the signal in a FFT if there is only one peak.

Comment: It would probably help if you could link to the paper.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but here are some [helpful visuals](https://dragonnotes.org/BoundaryIncidence/)